# Visualize $T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)=O(n\log(n))$ on a Tree

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I understand the mathematical proof for $T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)=O(n\log(n))$, however I cannot visually wrap my head around how it works. Intuitively, it just feels like it should $O(n^2)$. Can you show me why these two trains of thought are wrong:

1. Imagine a binary tree with $n$ nodes. On each node an $O(n)$ operation needs to be executed. A recursive function for this would thus be $T(n)=O(n)+T(\text{left})+T(\text{right})=2T(n/2)+O(n)$. Since there are $n$ nodes and the operation is $O(n)$ time to do thus $T(n)=nO(n)=O(n^2)$.
2. If you took this binary tree and simplified the operation to be $O(1)$, the complexity for this new tree would be $T(n)/O(n)=O(n\log(n))/O(n)=O(\log(n))$ (since things are now less complex by a factor of $O(n)$). However, it is mathematically proven that $T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(1)=O(n)$, not $O(\log(n))$.

*Note: I understand the mathematical proof for why $T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)=O(n\log(n))$ works. However I cannot visualize this or grasp it intuitively.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting what the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) describes. The task here is to process a tree, which is not exactly the same as just processing the nodes. Sorry for the pun, but it's like you're missing the tree <strike>in the forest</strike> behind the nodes. :-)

> On each node an $O(n)$ operation needs to be executed.

That's wrong — exactly because the real task is to process a tree, not just individual nodes one at a time. That's why the number of operations is ***NOT*** the same at different nodes. For example, simply by the definition of the function $T$: the top node requires $T(n)$ operations — because it's the root of a tree of size $n$ that we need to process; but each leaf, being a tree with a single node, requires only $T(1)$ operations, which is a constant.

> Since there are $n$ nodes and the operation is $O(n)$ time to do thus $T(n)=nO(n)=O(n^2)$.

Wrong, as explained above — different nodes require different time.

> If you took this binary tree and simplified the operation to be $O(1)$, …

Same thing.

> … the complexity for this new tree would be $T(n)/O(n)=O(n\log(n))/O(n)=O(\log(n))$ …

Sorry, but this simply doesn't make any sense. You started this calculation with the **assumption** that $T(n)=O(n\log(n))$, since that's what you replaced $T(n)$ with. Let's even leave aside the question of why you assume that from the beginning if that's what we're trying to deduce (even though it is a serious logical error). But if you already know what $T(n)$ is, how much sense does it make to "deduce" something different for it?

---

What the master theorem describes is the **divide-and-conquer** approach. Your main misconception is that something the same happens at each node, but that's not true. In fact, there are three things that happen at each node (for a binary tree):

1. We need to process the left subtree, at a cost of $T(\text{left})$;
2. We need to process the right subtree, at a cost of $T(\text{right})$;
3. And we need some time to perform *additional* operations at the node, such as forming subtrees, putting the results from the subtrees together, etc.

The "$+O(n)$" term in the recursive formula in your example refers to the computational cost of the last part only — for a node which is the root of a (sub)tree of size $n$; it is ***NOT*** the entire cost of what happens at a node, and it is ***NOT*** the same for all nodes. The total number of operations that we have to perform at such a node is by definition denoted $T(n)$, and it's in fact expressed by the recursive relation
$$T(n)=O(n)+T(\text{left})+T(\text{right})=2T(n/2)+O(n).$$

Comment: "You started this calculation with the assumption that $T(n)=O(nlog(n))$, since that's what you replaced $T(n)$ with". Sorry if it was not clear, but I was doing a proof by contradiction that $T(n)!=O(nlog(n))$. I started by assuming $T(n)!=O(nlog(n))$ is false so $T(n)=O(nlog(n))$, and then derived the contradiction that $O(n)=O(log(n))$. Also, I was not aware of the master theorem and learned the proofs a different way.

Comment: @Dan: Okay, I see! Then for a proof by contradiction this could be the starting point. But then, dividing everything by $O(n)$ is a very random unjustified step -- I don't see any logical reason for doing that, and so the "proof" falls apart anyway. As for the master theorem, you can ignore the reference. But still, the logic of divide-and-conquer is what's at work here.

Comment: Yes, I now see that is where the error lies